# If $F_m = 2^{2^m} + 1$ is prime (with $m \geq 1$), does it follow that $3 \mid \frac{F_m + 1}{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, conjectures, fermat-numbers

If $$F_m = 2^{2^m} + 1$$ is prime with $m \geq 1$, does it follow that $$3 \mid \frac{F_m + 1}{2}?$$

I have verified this to be true for $1 \leq m \leq 4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F_m=2^{2^m}+1$ are also known as [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). From 
$$2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 2^{2^m-1} \equiv (-1)^{2^m-1} \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$$
or 
$$2^{2^m-1} +1 = \frac{2^{2^m} +2}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
or 
$$\frac{F_m +1}{2}=\frac{2^{2^m} +2}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
Thus, $F_m$ should not necessarily be prime.

Comment: My profuse thanks for this, @rytbase!

Comment: Just realized my mistake in the original post.  Yes, this is correct.  Thanks again!  =)

Answer (score 2):

For any even $k>0$, $2^k\equiv 1\bmod 3$. So $3 \mid 2^k{+}2$ (and of course $3 \mid \frac{2^k{+}2}{2}$ also), regardless of whether $2^k{+}1$ is prime or not.